# A long colored absolute value into a determinant

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I'm looking to denote the area of a triangle by encasing a suitably-chosen expression in a pair of tall colored vertical lines. The idea is somewhat similar, but not identical, to the pair of vertical bars that are frequently used to denote the determinant of a matrix.

I suppose I could just write `$\text{area}(\triangle ABC)=\lvert \det(M) \rvert$`. For sure, though, I'd rather use a color other than black for the tall vertical lines. Something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\begin{document} 
\[
\text{area}(\triangle ABC)= 
%%  some code here ...
\frac{1}{2} \begin{vmatrix}
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots  \\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots  \\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots  
\end{vmatrix}   
%%  some more code here ...
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion, it would be better here to keep the coloured vertical rules for the absolute value and inside  write `\det\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}`. Graphically, it would look less ‘repetitive’.

Comment: @Bernard I agree with you, too. In fact, it says in the school books like your commentary. It's just that students are writing less and less and I want everything now. So I thought about class before the suspension because of the coronavirus to eliminate `\det`. My previous colleagues have always learned to write vertical bars and trouble if I write something other than that. :-) Just for color is important to understand the differences between determinant and absolute value.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the syntax you want. Do you want a redefinition of `\lvert`?

Comment: @F.Pantigny Like the last image using my MWE. I have put only the code without orange vertical bars created with Paints.

Comment: If I understand, you want a modification of the MWE in order to give the picture.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Yes. Exact! :-)

Comment: Unrelated: as always `\text` is wrong here either use operatorname or define `\area` properly

Comment: @daleif Your comment is welcome +1-

Comment: I'm not sure what should be the conveyed meaning. Note that denoting the determinant just with vertical bars is very old-fashioned.

Comment: @egreg It is only for my students that they not use the absolute value. Thank you very much for your comment. Also a your answer is welcome for me. +1

Comment: I'd more consistently use `\area(\triangle ABC)=\frac{1}{2}\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}\right|`. Using vertical bars with dual meaning introduces ambiguities. And you're missing 1/2 in front of the determinant.

Comment: @egreg Actually, my students renounced before the virus suspension at their class meetings and I explained a little bit about LaTeX. They were fascinated. To me, you're all welcome. Could you please put in your answer so I can show it to my students?

Comment: @egreg I have forgotten to put `\frac{1}{2}`...:( excuse me.

Answer (score 6):

I propose these three solutions, the second one with the absolute value sign slightly longer than the vertical lines of the determinant, the last one with the `\det` command, so that you can choose:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\[\text{area}(\triangle ABC)=\begin{array}{@{\color{Coral}\vrule width 0.6pt\,}c@{\,\color{Coral}\vrule width 0.6pt}}\begin{vmatrix}
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots
\end{vmatrix} \end{array}\]

\[\text{area}(\triangle ABC)={\color{Coral}\begin{vmatrix}{\color{black}\begin{vmatrix}
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots
\end{vmatrix}^{\mathstrut}_{\vphantom{j}}} \end{vmatrix} } \]

\[\text{area}(\triangle ABC)=\begin{array}{@{\color{Coral}\vrule width 0.6pt\mkern 3mu}c@{\color{Coral}\vrule width 0.6pt}}{\det}\mkern-6mu\begin{pmatrix}
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots
\end{pmatrix} \end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Coral" -- ooh la la! :-) +1

Comment: ooh la la!  ooh la la!  ooh la la!  ooh la la!  ooh la la! +1

Comment: Now who do I give the green tick now? I don't give it to anyone when all the answers are good. Excuse me.

Comment: For all answer my compliments and +1. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the  colour palette in xcolor does not comprise Carpaccio red, nor  Veronese – nor even ‘Cuisse de Nymphe émue’ ;o)

Comment: ahahaha  ;o) ;o) ;o) ;o) ;o) ;o)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\area}{area}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\orangebars[1]{%
  \begingroup \colorlet{current}{.} \color{orange} \left\vert 
  \begingroup \color{current} #1^{\mathstrut} \kern-\scriptspace \endgroup 
  \right\vert \endgroup
}

\begin{document} 
\[
  \area(\triangle ABC) =
  \orangebars{%
     \begin{vmatrix}
     \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
     \dots & \dots & \dots \\ 
     \dots & \dots & \dots 
  \end{vmatrix}}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Changing `orange` to `RedOrange` and `#1^{\mathstrut}` to `#1^{\strut}` generates the following output:

[image]

Just in case you find it difficult to decide on a color somewhere between orange and red, here they are along with three intermediate shades: Coral, Tomato, and OrangeRed (need to load the `xcolor` package with the option `svgnames`). :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\myrule{\rule{2em}{4em}}
\newcommand\manyhues{\color{orange}\myrule\color{Coral}\myrule%
  \color{Tomato}\myrule\color{OrangeRed}\myrule\color{red}\myrule}
\begin{document} 
\manyhues
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it my impression but the orange colour has faded and is thinner? :-) Is there a toner deficiency? :-))))) Can you make it a little longer leaving this code?

Comment: @Sebastiano - Does the color scheme in the addendum I just posted pass muster? :-)

Comment: Now who do I give the green tick now? I don't give it to anyone when all the answers are good. Excuse me.

Comment: For all answer my compliments and +1. :-)

Comment: You could add `\colorlet{current}{.}` before `\color{orange}`, and then use `\color{current}` instead of `\color{black}`.

Comment: @egreg - Great suggestion! :-) I'll update my answer right away.

Comment: You should also add `\kern-\scriptspace` before closing the inner group, because the fake superscript adds `\scriptspace` and so the closing orange bar is farther away than the opening one. Instead of `\left\lvert` and `\right\rvert` you could also use `\vrule width 1pt` to get a thicker bar. However for this you need to change the outer `\begingroup...\endgroup` into `{...}`.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for pointing out the `\kern-\scriptspace` issue; I've incorporated the suggestion into the answer. In order to implement the second suggestion -- replacing `\left\vert` and `\right\vert` with `\vrule width 1pt` -- I suppose that it's also necessary to change `#1^{\mathstrut}` to `#1^{\mathstrut}_{\mathstrut}`.

Answer (score 3):

A solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyph

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \BigAbs }{ m }
  {  
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { $ #1 $ }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box + 3 mm }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box + 3 mm }
    \mathopen{
    \color { red }
    \vrule height \l_tmpa_dim depth \l_tmpb_dim width 1 pt } 
    \; \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box \; 
    \mathclose{
    \color { red }
    \vrule height \l_tmpa_dim depth \l_tmpb_dim width 1 pt }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 
\[\text{area}(\triangle ABC)=
\BigAbs{\begin{vmatrix}
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots  \\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots  \\ 
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots  
\end{vmatrix}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now who do I give the green tick now? I don't give it to anyone when all the answers are good. Excuse me.

Comment: For all answer my compliments and +1. :-)